# Javascript - html local storage - Store and recall text input as a variable

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, local-storage

This is the basic structure of my html page.
Clicking the

rememberer , stores the data in input text box to local storage as a string.
Clicking

recaller, loads the stored data onto

recalledtext.
I am developing this to be used in Phone Gap.

```
<input type="text" id="textline" />

<p id="rememberer" onclick='myfunction1()'>remember text</p>
<p id="recaller" onclick='myfunction2()'>recall text</p>

<p id="recalledtext" >Loading</p>
```

The code is as follows

```
function myfunction1(){
//remember code
var texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').innerHTML ;
localStorage.mynumber = texttosave;
}


function myfunction2(){
//recall code
document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML = localStorage.mynumber; 
}
```

I am confused why this code is not functioning.
Also I need to know can I use this code alone without using phoneGap APIs to store data that can be recalled even after the session is closed and opened later on.

Please share your experiences.

Comment: an input doesn't have innerHtml. Learn how to use basic javascript debugging tools

Comment: There are potential pitfalls from using [innerHTML](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=30&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=innerhtml+problems&oq=innerhtml+problems&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l2.293.293.0.1062.2.2.0.0.0.0.178.327.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.53.hp..1.1.149.0.KuZX1_JWqbk) too.

Comment: @Andy can you tell me what are those pitfalls

Comment: There's a link on the "innerHTML" part of what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) for session and local storage - it defines methods for getting and setting stored keys

You are going to want to use the `setItem` and `getItem` like so:

```
function myfunction1(){
    //remember code
    var texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').innerHTML ;
    localStorage.setItem('mynumber', texttosave);
}


function myfunction2(){
    //recall code
    document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML 
           = localStorage.getItem('mynumber'); 
}
```

There are a couple other useful methods as well such as `removeItem(key)`

this works for the [Phonegap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage) as well as standard browser implementations - if `window.localStorage` is supported